# ActiveX Flash component in C# .NET 2.0 Application causes memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, com, activex

We have a C#/.NET 2.0 WinForm with an ActiveX ShockwaveFlashObject control on it. The program loops through a schedule of content and displays it over and over on the control, fullscreen, like this:

```
axFlash.BringToFront();
axFlash.Movie = scheduleItem.FilePath;
axFlash.Show();
axFlash.Play();
```

This works great, but after a couple of days running, the form on which the Flash ActiveX control resides will throw an exception like this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CallWindowProc(IntPtr wndProc, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Looking at the taskmanager, I see that our program has allocated virtually all of the available memory on the machine. (~500MB)

- Are ActiveX (COM) components unmanaged by Garbage Collection?
- Is there some known memory leak in Flash9.ocx or Flash10.ocx?
- Any ideas how I can get an external component (Flash ActiveX in this case) to release resources back without restarting the program? Could periodically re-creating the ShockwaveFlashObject with a "new" fix things?
- Maybe restarting the program periodically is the only good option?

Comment: Hi Adam,

Did you find any solution to this problem.  I run into same problem as you had a year ago that I am tyring to embed flash into a C# winform application.  This app needs to run without restarting as a digital signage display. 

Please let me know if you find a workaround for this memory leak issue.  I would greatly appreciate your help.
thx..N

Comment: Never did come up with a solution that didn't involve restarting the application. For us, our solution was to develop a small Watchdog application that gets started (if not running already) from the main application. The watchdog simply checks every 10 seconds or so to see if the main application still has a process running, and if it doesn't, it starts one. Much sturdier than trying to restart from the main app. And no one seems to notice that the digital signage resets a time or two every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX components typically are written in unmanaged code, and therefore would not be cleaned up by the CLR garbage collector.  You need to ensure you release any references to the ActiveX control.  I think this would only create an issue though if you are recreating the ActiveX control a lot.

You can use perfmon to measure memory usage by the CLR and memory usage overall.  You can use this to narrow down who is leaking the memory.  (the difference would be due to unmanaged code, like the activex control)

If you do isolate it to the ActiveX or flash control, trying stubbing out those objects with a fake object that doesn't consume memory.  This should let you verify it is the source of the leak.

Comment: Well, the application itself shouldn't be leaking, it is Garbage Collected.  So that leaves the only ActiveX (unmanaged probably) code in the application, the Flash component, as the only culprit. This makes sense too, since the Flash is what was obviously causing the biggest problem when this was a Delphi/Win32 program - you would actually see the Flash stop loading shortly before "the end."

Comment: Its always good to measure to be sure.  Maybe the CLR has reserved a whole bunch of memory ahead of time, causing the flash program to run into the out-of-memory condition first.  So I don't think that proves where the leak is... better to measure and be sure.

Comment: @Adam Nofsinger: Having a memory leak caused by managed code a .NET app is nothing uncommon. There are many aspects that may prevent certain object from being garbage collected that may not be clear to you, mostly references held by other live objects.

Comment: Although not as frequent a problem as on other platforms, .NET memory leaks can actually be more difficult to detect and fix, simply because the problem isn't always that "you forgot the release a resource", but that some complex network of inter-references prevents objects from being garbage collected. I had just gone hunting for some myself...

Answer (score 0):

If the code in your C# application is simplistic I would recommend just writing it in AIR.  This way you aren't dealing with ActiveX and any bugs that Flash's OCX may have.

Comment: Hmm... some stuff might be difficult to port to AIR. Besides this, changing the platform/language AGAIN (this was originally written in Delphi/Win32) might increase the number of problems, not necessarily reduce it.  And who is to say AIR isn't going to have all the same problems that Flash's OCX will - I mean, they are both by Macromedia/Adobe.

Comment: The thing is that the OCX is not Flash itself, it is just an ActiveX wrapper around the flash component. The leak could easily be in that shim and not the actual player code itself.  Perhaps there is a small leak that happens in the OCX when a movie is set when one is already currently set.  Going directly with AIR would get rid of that shim.

Comment: It would be easy to do a hardcoded test in AIR that just loops through a few movies over and over.  Let it run for a couple days and see if the memory usage is high.

Answer (score 0):

Only managed code is garbage collected.  ActiveX code use standard COM style collection (AddRef/ReleaseRef).  When done using a com reference, set it to null just to be safe, or wrap a using() around it.

Comment: The problem there is that the program will never be DONE using it. It is a constantly running Media Player for Digital Signage. Perhaps you mean to imply that calling .Dispose() on it occasionally and then re-creating the instance with "new ShockwaveFlashObject()" would be useful?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but this is my 5 cents:

I think that the .swf (the flash you are playing) is causing the memory leak, i had this issues with flash some time ago, and the solution was to carefully go through the code and to properly stop/clear all timers, dispose all used objects etc. I was debugging with processXP, to see how the flash manages memory, and if you have bad coding practice (not removing EventListeners, not stopping timers, creating new instances and stop using them without proper dispose of them), in time reaches the memory limits and crashes. (crash happens no matter where you have the flash, in browser, stand alone, inside actives etc).

If you are the creator of the .swf, you could pay more attention to that and you wouldn't have to restart your program, but if you are getting it from other sources, you would have to go with closing it periodically, because you don't know how well is coded inside.