# Creating a watch dog to start an application on crash

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to create a watch dog. in C#  Which will keep looking for a exe if it is running or not if that exe is not running. Watch dog should automatically start the exe.

Example :

My exe is notepad.exe. I want to run a watch dog to see notepad.exe is running all the time. If some body closed it or some hoe some crash has happened watch dog should start the notepad.exe automatically.

Please help me with some snipet or some link for this approch.

Thanks

Comment: what have your tried?

Comment: and a simple search would have found this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146381/whats-the-best-way-to-watchdog-a-desktop-application  That took 20 secs....

Comment: Write a windows service which starts a timer and executes a Process.GetProcesses() regularly. Check if the list returned contains your process. If it doesn't, start it.

Answer (score 0):

start here

```
   Process.GetProcessesByName();
```

would be good to see evidence of thought, attempts research etc...