# Methode for restart

Tags: c#, wpf

I need a Method to restart my Program.
I try to make a loop but in the partial class no Loop is allowed. 
How can i make a Method with a Loop that includes the Button?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
```

I am open for every comment and help.
Thanks Morwoi.

Comment: What do you mean by restart? Why shoud a loop not be allowed? It's quite unclear what you want.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779405/how-do-i-restart-my-c-sharp-winform-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restart your application, you can use the following code.

```
Application.Restart();
```

This can be used in any function or trigger.

Comment: That method doesn't event exist...?