# Application.Restart() Not running after DialogResult is hit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I can’t find a way to get the `Application.Restart()` to work after clicking out of the `MessageBox`, it seems to close the existing instance but doesn’t start a new instance.  I can get it to perform pretty much anything else I put in there (another `messagebox.show()`, show another form, etc ).  This is a single instance app and I don’t seem to have any trouble on the other button in my app that performs `Application.Restart()`.  If there’s a better way to go than `Application.Restart()`, I’d go for it, but it seems like every alternative I’ve tried from other threads does the same thing, exit and not start a new one.

```
Dim result As DialogResult
MessageBox.Show( _
"Server is busy.  Please try again.", _
"Program", _
MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

 If result = 0 Then

     Application.Restart()

 End If
```

Comment: a) you arent assigning the result of that MessageBox to result b) if they do hit OK, the value is 1 not 0 c) since it is Modal why do you have to check anything?  The user does not appear to have a choice. d) cant the app wait a while and try again rather than immediately restart and presumably retry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779405/how-do-i-restart-my-c-sharp-winform-application